# Is it possible to set the button font for DevExpress ButtonEdit when it is in Glyph mode

Tags: devexpress-windows-ui

I want to use codepoint #1F50D (magnifying glass) as the character displayed by the button of the DevExpress WinForm ButtonEdit control. Most fonts don't have a glyph at that codepoint, but some do.  Can the button's font be set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`EditorButton.Appearance`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraEditorsControlsEditorButton_Appearancetopic) property to modify the font of button.
Here is example:

```cs
var button = buttonEdit2.Properties.Buttons[0];

button.Appearance.Font = new Font("Segoe UI Symbol", 8.25F);
button.Appearance.Options.UseFont = true;
```

Also you can modify the appearance in Visual Studio directly:
[image: Visual Studio]

Here is the result:
[image: Result]